# Nextjs not compiling all tailwindcss classes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, postcss, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use Tailwindcss in my Nextjs project. The problem is that some of the classes that Tailwind Css has built-in are not working (like grid or active: pseudo class).

I have this page:

**Index.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

const Index = () => (
  <div className="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
  </div>
);
export default Index;
```

That renders:

[image: View without grid clasess]

instead of:

[image: View with grid clasess]

I configured Nextjs to use Tailwindcss (Using just postcss.config.js without Nextcss, since postcss is already in this version of Nextjs v9.2.1)

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ["tailwindcss", "autoprefixer"]
};
```

and added the global `styles/main` with:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

to `_app.jsx` like this:

**pages/_app.jsx**

```
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
import React from "react";
import App from "next/app";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import withRedux from "next-redux-wrapper";
import initStore from "../rx";
import "../styles/index.css";

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
const CustomApp = ({ Component, pageProps, store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </Provider>
);

CustomApp.getInitialProps = async appContext => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

  return { ...appProps };
};

export default withRedux(initStore)(CustomApp);
```

(Ignore redux implementation)

As you can see, some of the classes are being compiled but some others are not, when I enter the dev console and search for grid, there's not a class with such a name. What am I doing wrong in the configuration?

Comment: you need to import tailwindcss in postcss.config.js and import as variable not as a string should work for you.if you can share a github repo it will be more useful

Comment: @Nikas The official documentation of Nextjs says: _[Do not use require() to import the PostCSS Plugins. Plugins must be provided as strings.](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-postcss-config#customizing-plugins)_ (at the end of the article). However the problem could be that the default configuration of the autoprefixer is disabled. I'll link a github repo with the project soon.

Comment: Make sure you are using tailwindcss 1.2. Grid seems to be a fairly recent addition.

Comment: Do you have a tailwind.config.js? If so, can you add it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my problem was the version of Tailwind I was using (and the variants I configured). Creating a new project and installing the newest version of Tailwind fixed the Grid problem. And the problem related to the pseudo-classes was caused because Tailwind does not include by default all the utilities variants. [Default variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants#default-variants-reference)

Comment: Thanks, pasting in the variants from the doc into my tailwind.config.js fixed that some classes were not working in nextjs for me